# Jquery, append sumindo

Tags: jquery, ajax, append

boa tarde! Meu Jquery está adicionando os resultados obtidos via ajax e eles estão sumindo. O que pode estar acontencendo? E como resolver?
Obrigado

```
var _urlSearchInput;
var _urlSearch; 

$('#vai').click(function(){

    _urlSearchInput = $('#campo-busca').val();
    _urlSearch = window.location.origin + "/search/" + _urlSearchInput + "/";
    //alert(_urlSearch);
    //alert(_urlSearchInput);

    $.ajax({
        url: _urlSearch,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        success: function(json) {
            var html; 
            var matias = json; 
            if(typeof json == 'string'){ 
                matias = JSON.parse(json); 
            } 
            for(item in matias){
                        html += '<div class="media wow fadeInDown animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: fadeInDown;">'; 
                        if (typeof matias[item].midias['102x112'] != 'undefined'){
                        html +=     '<a href="#" class="media-left">';
                        html +=         '<img alt="" src="' + matias[item].midias['102x112']  + '">';
                        html +=     '</a>';
                        }
                        html +=     '<div class="media-body">';
                        html +=         '<h4 class="media-heading">';
                        html +=             '<a href="'+ matias[item].url +'">' + matias[item].title + '</a>';
                        html +=         '</h4>';
                        html +=         '<p>' + ( !matias[item].description ? '' : matias[item].description) + '</p>';
                        html +=     '</div>';
                        html +='</div>';            
            }

                $('#resultados-busca').append(html.replace("undefined", ""));   
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: tenta remover essa classe `animated` parece que é uma animação de `CSS`

Comment: Já tentei... tentei sem nenhuma classe de CSS e mesmo assim nada.

Comment: os elementos permanecem na `DOM` ou são removidos? adiciona um `return false;` antes de fechar a ultima chave do `success`;

Comment: Os elementos não permanecem na DOM. Eles são criados e depois somem. Adicionei o return false antes do fechamento da chave do sucess... nada mudou. =/

Comment: consegue adicionar um retorno do seu json para eu fazer um teste aqui?

Comment: Como que eu devo proceder para conseguir simular isso? Os dados estão sendo passado por um servidor interno..

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui "resolver" a questão do sumiço das DIVs adicionada pelo append adicionando o "event".
Agora o resultado é adicionado, porém, quando eu procuro outra coisa ele adiciona embaixo do resultado anterior.
Gostaria que ele apagasse os resultados da busca anterior.
Como devo proceder?

Obrigado

Código atual:

```
$('#vai').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();     
    var _urlSearchInput = $('#campo-busca').val();
    var _urlSearch = window.location.origin + "/search/" + _urlSearchInput + "/";

    $.ajax({
        url: _urlSearch,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",

        success: function(json) {
            var html; 
            var matias = json; 
            if(typeof json == 'string'){ 
                matias = JSON.parse(json); 
            } 

            for(item in matias){
                html += '<div class="item fadeInDown">'; 
                if (typeof matias[item].midias['102x112'] != 'undefined'){
                html +=     '<a href="#" class="media-left">';
                html +=         '<img alt="" src="' + matias[item].midias['102x112']  + '">';
                html +=     '</a>';
                }
                html +=     '<div class="media-body">';
                html +=         '<h4 class="media-heading">';
                html +=             '<a href="'+ matias[item].url +'">' + matias[item].title + '</a>';
                html +=         '</h4>';
                html +=         '<p>' + ( !matias[item].description ? '' : matias[item].description) + '</p>';
                html +=     '</div>';
                html +=  '</div>';
                html +=  '<hr>';            
            }
                if(html != "")
                    $("#resultados-busca").append(html.replace("undefined", ""));   
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Primareimente, aconselho que não uso o campo de resposta para fazer uma pergunta, sempre que precisar você pode editar sua pergunta inicial. Agora como sugestão de solução tente usar `.html()` ao invés de `.append()` e veja o que ocorre.

Comment: Funcionou alterando o .append() para o .html().

Comment: Muito obrigado!!